# Are "functional units" the same as "issue slots"?

Tags: computer-architecture

I study computer hardware and a multiple issue system. I'm told there are "four functional units" but I don't understand what that means.

Comment: A functional unit is anything that performs an identifiable function. An ALU, Multiplier, Divider, etc. Some functional units may perform several related functions, but can only perform one of them at a time. Multiple ALUs, for example, are possible. And this would mean more than one function unit, say N ALUs, even though all N of them provide the same functions. There is often a "registration station" used to allocate functional units and another method used to release them when they've completed their function, so they can be used again. Issue slots are superscaler and not equal in meaning.

Comment: jonk has explained it well anyway, but a functional unit is a distinct block of circuitry that performs a distinct job within a circuit, most often a digital logic circuit. Example units are ALU, bus interface unit, cache controller. Issue slots are quite different, you can Google: "issue slot" cpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these terms are generic - they don't, in isolation, have any well defined meaning. A 'functional unit' could be anything from a edge-detect/trigger module up to a whole CPU.

Functional units are just a grouping of logic with an easily defined purpose. The level of abstraction is up to the person using the term.

An 'issue slot' does imply some degree of parallelism in the design, although it is ambiguous what is being issued. Most likely a micro-op, or (less likely) a bus transfer but this shouldn't be assumed. How the issue slots are 'driven' is also not defined. They could be split by function, driven from a buffer/queue, etc.

The question implies a more fundamental gap in the description which you're trying to interpret. It's possible that the structure presented to you is more important than the way it was described.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

Functional units are just units that perform logic or arithmetic functions. An ALU is a functional unit that performs addition, subtraction, logical operations etc according to the instruction you supply it. There may be several ALUs, plus other functional units dedicated to more complex operations such as multiplication, division etc.

You may find that ALU operations take one clock cycle, but multiplication takes two and division takes four cycles, to save space and gates in these less frequently used functional units. (Or in a DSP where fast math is essential, you may have several multipliers and each takes one clock cycle.

Now, especially where different units take different lengths of time, scheduling instructions so that (a) the max possible are carried out in each clock cycle and (b) results all arrive in the correct order, becomes quite a complex process.

Each instruction is fed into an issue slot, to wait for its functional unit AND all its dependencies (input values) to be ready. For example, adding two numbers, you may have to wait for one to come from memory, and the other to come from the (slow) division unit. This instruction waits in this issue slot until both inputs are ready AND no earlier instruction is using the adder (ALU functional unit).

So in one architecture, there may be several instructions waiting for a resource, each in its own issue slot. But every architecture is different, according to the decisions the architects made how to maximise performance or minimise size and power.